# if else statement not giving expected answer

Tags: c, if-statement, case

The values entered are not matching with the output grade as it is giving 10 grade even when the conditions for 10 are not met. 
the issue is that on entering hardness 50 strength 5600 and carbon 0.7 its giving grade 10 while for grade 10 carbon should be less than 0.7?
    #include 
    #include 
    #include

```
int main() {
    // program grade the steel on quality basis

    int hardness;
    int strength;
    float carbon;

    printf("Enter the hardness of steel:");    // condition 1  hardness should be >= 50
    scanf("%d", &hardness);

    printf("Enter the tensile strength:");     // condition 2  strength should be >= 5600
    scanf("%d", &strength);

    printf("Enter carbon content:");           // condition 3  carbon less than 0.7
    scanf("%.2f", &carbon);


    if ((hardness >= 50) && (carbon < 0.7) && (strength >= 5600)) {        // all true
        printf("\ngrade = 10");
    }
    else if ((hardness >= 50) && (carbon < 0.7) && (strength <= 5600)) {     // 1 and 2 true
        printf("\ngrade = 9");
    }
    else if ((hardness <= 50) && (carbon < 0.7) && (strength >= 5600)) {    // 2 and 3 true
        printf("\ngrade = 8");
    }
    else if ((hardness >= 50) && (carbon > 0.7) && (strength >= 5600)) {    // 1 and 3 true
        printf("\ngrade = 7");
    }
    else if ((hardness >= 50) && (carbon > 0.7) && (strength <= 5600)) {    // any one true
        printf("\ngrade = 6");
    }
    else if ((hardness <= 50) && (carbon < 0.7) && (strength <= 5600)) {    // any one true
        printf("\ngrade = 6");
    }   
    else if ((hardness <= 50) && (carbon < 0.7) && (strength >= 5600)) {    // any one true
        printf("\ngrade = 6");
    }
    else {
        printf("\ngrade = 5");                     // none true
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `case` would be appropriate for this ...

Comment: change `scanf("%.2f", &carbon);` to `scanf("%f", &carbon);`

Comment: You might note that if the carbon content is exactly 0.7 (it's a delicate question whether that is ever really true — probably not given that `carbon` is a `float` and `0.7` is a `double`), then you never match the value.

Answer (score 3):

Use of `"%.2f"` as format specifier is not correct in `scanf`. It is good for `printf` but not `scanf`.

It's a good idea to always check the return value of `scanf` to make sure that the function was able to read the expected data.

```
if ( scanf("%.2f", &carbon) != 1 )
{
   // Deal with error.
}
```

Add similar checks to the other `scanf` calls.

I think changing the above format specifier to `"%f"` should fix your problem. Add the check still.

```
if ( scanf("%f", &carbon) != 1 )
{
   // Deal with error.
}
```

Comment: And add the checks on the other two `scanf()` calls.  And it is always a good idea to print out the inputs to make sure the program got the values you think it got.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the format specifier(.2f) in scanf statement.
%.2f is generally used to print 2 digits after the point
**In C,all float literals are stored as double precision values.So we need to specify that we are using float i.e single precision by appending the values by f.Check the change of code**
if you want your carbon to be rounded of to 2 digit precision, you can use carbon = ceilf(carbon*100)/100.0;
When you post your question next time, post your input for which it fails, you will get quick reply
And you can write this with less number of comparisons- here is the working code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void) {
int hardness;
int strength;
float carbon;
printf("Enter the hardness of steel:"); 
scanf("%d", &hardness);
printf("Enter the tensile strength:"); 
scanf("%d", &strength);
printf("Enter carbon content:");
scanf("%f", &carbon);
if ((hardness >= 50) && (carbon < 0.7f) && (strength >= 5600))
    printf("\ngrade = 10");
else if ((hardness >= 50) && (carbon < 0.7f))
    printf("\ngrade = 9");
else if ((carbon < 0.7f) && (strength >= 5600))   
    printf("\ngrade = 8");
else if ((hardness >= 50) && (strength >= 5600)) 
    printf("\ngrade = 7");
else if ((hardness >= 50) || (carbon > 0.7f) || (strength <= 5600))
    printf("\ngrade = 6");
else
    printf("\ngrade = 5");                  
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: still the issue is that on entering hardness 50 strength 5600 and carbon 0.7 its giving grade 10 while for grade 10 carbon should be less than 0.7

Comment: [sigh] 0.69999999999999999999999999999999999 is less than 0.7